# Ssh access to azure debian vm suddenly stopped

Tags: macos, azure, ssh, virtual-machine, azure-vm

I've create azure debian vm and during the creation process the .pem file with private key was created for me. And I have downloaded it to my Mac OS machine.

I've copied the pem file to `~/.ssh/vmuser.pem`
I've set the permissions of the file to `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/vmuser.pem`

Then I've tried to ssh into the vm using:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/vmuser.pem vmuser@vm.ho.st.name`

First time I did it it asked me if the fingerprint is correct, which I said yes. And **I was able** to ssh into the machine.

But when I droped the session and I'm retrying the command:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/vmuser.pem vmuser@vm.ho.st.name`

I'm getting
`Permission denied (publickey).`
error

Comment: Maybe you can try to delete the record in the file `~/.ssh/know_hosts` for your VM and then ssh the VM again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a ssh-keygen for your host machine. Then update the public key for your debian vm to reflect that of the /.ssh/id_rsa.pub file. I recently encountered a similar issue when trying to ssh into a ubuntu vm.

Comment: I've run
`az vm show 
    --resource-group <resource_group> 
    --name <vm_name> 
    --query osProfile.linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys[0].keyData 
    -o tsv`
and it seems that the public key is correct

Comment: I would double check the public key. If you can update it it might solve your problem. Let me know how it works for you.